# XP Missing AD in security location

Tags: security, windows-xp, permissions

I have a few Windows XP clients that are part of a domain, when trying to set the permissions on the security tab and pressing location to search the AD for users it only presents the local machine...

So I follow this path

Right click folder > Properties > Security > Add

in the locations field where I would normally see the windows domain, I am only seeing the local machine name???

So only users that have a local account can be added to the folders permissions...

Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Check your DNS resolution is working ok, can you resolve a Domain Controller for those machines? You may be able to log on ok because you are using Cached logins, but to get access to the domain to set permissions, you need to talk to a DC.

Answer (score 0):

ping the fqdn of the domain, if that works then in this case I don't think the workstation is a member of the domain anymore.